# Add & Remove prefix to GUID via ModelBuilder conversion

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to add and remove a prefix to a GUID on each request to my service.

Something like this

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                .Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasConversion(
                    v => PrefixConstant + v,
                    v => Guid.Parse(v.Substring(PrefixConstant.Length)));
```

Where `PrefixConstant` is just a string holding something like `"ABC_"`. The idea is to store the id as a GUID, but return it with a prefix to the client.

The above hasn't been working too well with an error of `id is of type uuid but expression is of type text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The idea is to store the id as a GUID, but return it with a prefix to the client.

The implementation though does the exact opposite. The defined value conversion here

```
.Property(e => e.Id)
.HasConversion(
    v => PrefixConstant + v, // (1)
    v => Guid.Parse(v.Substring(PrefixConstant.Length)) // (2)
)
```

implies that the class property `Id` type is `Guid`, stored as `string` in the database, and using (1) for writing and (2) when reading the database value.

So all you need is to simply exchange the types and conversions, e.g. making the `Id` property type `string`

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and configuring to/from database `Guid` conversion

```
.Property(e => e.Id)
.HasConversion(
    v => Guid.Parse(v.Substring(PrefixConstant.Length)),
    v => PrefixConstant + v
)
```

For more info, see the EF Core documentation of [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) and [`ValueConverter<TModel,TProvider>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.valueconversion.valueconverter-2?view=efcore-3.1) class.

Comment: Ivan, this looks like the right solution. I had actually attempted doing it the other way around (because the docs make that clear), but I had failed to turn the Id property into a string in my entity. That's what I was missing! I can't test this right now but will do tomorrow and will hopefully approve the answer if all goes well. Thank you!

Comment: this solution also assumes that Id in my database is a Guid right? even if the Id in the entity is a string

Comment: @jgozal Correct. The property type is from `e => e.Id` (now `string`). The database type is from the generic type argument of `HasConversion`, which is implied from the result type of the first expression, in this case `v => Guid.Parse(...)` returns `Guid`. This is just a shortcut for creating [ValueConverter<string, Guid>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#the-valueconverter-class)

Comment: woops so sorry @Ivan Stoev, this is my first time creating a bounty question. I thought it would be automatically awarded to you upon approving your answer. Just took care of awarding it right now!

Answer (score 1):

The reason of error is almost clear. You get error because you want to convert `Guid` to `string` and save it to database column whose type is `Guid`!

I think you choose a wrong option. `HasConversion` is suitable for situations where you want convert data and save converted data, but your intention is just displaying property to client in another way (Your concern here is about UI, not logic). So I think doing change in your model is very better option:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    private const string PrefixConstant = "ABC_";
    private Guid id;
    public string Id
    {
        set => id = Guid.Parse(value.Replace(PrefixConstant, string.Empty));
        get => $"{PrefixConstant}{id.ToString()}";
    }
}
```

It's just to show you the idea. Even this code is not a best practice if you use that as your `DataModel` because you shouldn't use your `DataModel` instead of `ViewModel`.
My intention here as `MyEntity` is `ViewModel` not `DataModel` and you should pay attention to their differences and separate them from each other.